# Get all Personal Views from a SharePoint List

Tags: list-view, impersonation, service-account

I understand that I can impersonate a user with a user's token to get their personal view, but is there a less brute way of getting personal views?

Is there an account I'm over-looking that has "super access" that would be able to return all personal views? Or is iterating through each user and impersonating the only option here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges** method for super access.

Executes the specified method with Full Control rights even if the user does not otherwise have Full Control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx

```
static void GetViews(SPSite site)
        {
            SPWeb spweb = site.OpenWeb();
            foreach(SPUser oUser in spweb.AllUsers)
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SPSite oElevSite = new SPSite(site.ID, oUser.UserToken);
                        SPWeb oElevWeb = oElevSite.RootWeb;
                        SPList splist = oElevWeb.Lists["CustomStatusList"];
                        SPViewCollection views = splist.Views;
                        foreach (SPView view in views)
                        {
                            if (view.PersonalView)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(oUser.Name +":"+ view.Title);
                            }
                        }
                        oElevWeb.Dispose();
                        oElevSite.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm running this through powershell using several accounts. My administrator account, farm account, none work. These accounts have full control on the site.

Comment: your code performs the brute method i'm trying to avoid of iterating through each user.

Comment: there is no other option.